# how to check for numbers and letters in python

Tags: python, arduino

i need to find numbers and letters in a serial input from an arduino mega.
i have a 4x4 keypad hooked up to it.
when something is clicked, the arduino sends the letter/number to the python program.
for some reason, the python program cant read it.

python code:

```
import serial
import time
import keyboard

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM9', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    key = arduino.read()
    print(key)
    if key == "1":
        keyboard.send("e")
```

arduino code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
const int ROW_NUM = 4;
const int COLUMN_NUM = 4;
char keys[ROW_NUM][COLUMN_NUM] = {
  {'1','2','3', 'A'},
  {'4','5','6', 'B'},
  {'7','8','9', 'C'},
  {'*','0','#', 'D'}
};
byte pin_rows[ROW_NUM] = {42, 40, 38, 36};
byte pin_column[COLUMN_NUM] = {34, 32, 30, 28};
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), pin_rows, pin_column, ROW_NUM, COLUMN_NUM );
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key){
    Serial.println(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to check the key is char or number, you should use "isdigit" or "isalpha" functions :

"1".isdigit() => True
"A".isdigit() => False

"1".isalpha() => False
"A".isalpha() => True

Comment: sorry if i sound dumb, but is this for the arduino, or python.

Comment: i also am getting a string from the serial connection, could this check an entire string at once?

Comment: That's for python